# Phpmailer sending Blank Emails with AddStringAttachment()

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I found a lot of answer around **stackoverflow.com** but haven't helped me , so i am forced to ask

**Problem:Phpmailer sending  mails but Blank Emails! no body no attachment !**

```
//Create a new PHPMailer instance
$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host       = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com"; // SMTP server
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Port       = 465;  // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server; 465 for ssl and 587 for tls
$mail->Username   = "services@domain.xxx"; // Gmail account username
$mail->Password   = "pwd";        // Gmail account password


//$mail->Mailer = 'smtp';
//Set who the message is to be sent from
$mail->SetFrom(service_mail_d, 'XXXX Services');
//Set an alternative reply-to address
$mail->AddReplyTo(service_mail_d, 'XXXX Services');
//Set who the message is to be sent to
$mail->AddAddress("testcenter@xxxx.xxxxx", "Client1");
//Set the subject line
$mail->Subject = "service_order_subject" ;
//Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body
$mail->MsgHTML("<h1>Simple TEST</h1>");
$mail->AddStringAttachment($generator_file_content,$generatorId ."html",'UTF-8','text/html');
 //Send the message, check for errors
$mailSend=$mail->Send();
```

**Update:**

> its sending mail and MsgBody can be seen if no StringAttachment is added !

Comment: do you get the body if you dont include the attachment?

Comment: try adding $mail->IsHTML(true);

Comment: @Rohit  hopes its not needed with $mail->MsgHTML() (at least in newer version of phpmailer)

Comment: @Dagon if i don't include the attachment  Msg Body is visible  in received mail

Answer (score 1):

Change the code from:

```
$mail->AddStringAttachment($generator_file_content,$generatorId ."html",'UTF-8','text/html');
 //Send the message, check for errors
$mailSend=$mail->Send();
```

to:

```
$mail->AddStringAttachment($generator_file_content,$generatorId ."html");
// 'UTF-8','text/html');

if($mail->Send())
    echo "Mail sent";
else
    echo "Mail NOT sent";
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your misunderstanding of the "encoding" parameter. This parameter does not indicate the encoding of the file, but the target MIME encoding for the file. From the [documentation](https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer), you can use any of these values:

- base64
- 7bit
- 8bit
- binary
- quoted-printable